# Execution flow in react native after navigation.navigate

Tags: typescript, react-native, navigation, expo

Need suggestion and advice,

I am using the below 2 lines of code in react native expo component,

```
this.props.navigation.navigate("App");
 patchUser(this.state.dataSource.userInfo.username, this.state.dataSource.userInfo.firstName,this.state.dataSource.userInfo.lastName, this.state.dataSource.lastLoginTime);
```

my question:

Will "patchUser()" be called always, since this.props.navigation.navigate("App") has been executed before and it takes to another component ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When navigating to "App", the screen with your code snippet above remains mounted, as described [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-lifecycle/). Therefore, your code should still execute.